# How to save the WindRose plot result as summary table?

Tags: r, openair

```
 library("openair")
 library("plyr")
```

I have the following the line code and I need to summarize the result from the WindRose plot in compass values (i.e. N=1000,NE-6859,W=9585,etc). The function is based on the package `openair`. I do not know how to extract from the plot, the frecuency values for each wind direction paddle.

`windRose(viento,"WS_ms_Avg","WindDir",type="mes", paddle=FALSE,layout=c(3,4))`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
tmp_1 <- windRose(mydata)

head(tmp_1$data)

##                           default Interval1 Interval2 Interval3 Interval4
## 1 01 January 1998 to 23 June 2005 0.9918888  4.560834  6.322132  6.838161
## 2 01 January 1998 to 23 June 2005 0.4665894  2.679027  4.344535  5.113944
## 3 01 January 1998 to 23 June 2005 0.4264195  2.479722  4.339900  4.956354
## 4 01 January 1998 to 23 June 2005 0.5561993  2.399382  3.589031  4.018540
## 5 01 January 1998 to 23 June 2005 0.6056392  2.717652  4.105060  4.863654
## 6 01 January 1998 to 23 June 2005 0.7122441  3.797605  7.341831 10.246427
##    wd calm panel.fun mean.wd freqs
## 1  30  0.1      4.49  -118.3  4426
## 2  60  0.1      4.49  -118.3  3310
## 3  90  0.1      4.49  -118.3  3208
## 4 120  0.1      4.49  -118.3  2601
## 5 150  0.1      4.49  -118.3  3148
## 6 180  0.1      4.49  -118.3  6632


tmp_2 <- windRose(mydata, type="year")

head(tmp_2$data)

##   year Interval1 Interval2 Interval3 Interval4  wd calm panel.fun mean.wd
## 1 1998 1.5962554  6.204993  7.057129  7.093135  30  0.2      4.38  -110.4
## 2 1998 0.5160826  3.300528  4.176668  4.200672  60  0.2      4.38  -110.4
## 3 1998 0.2760442  1.500240  2.472396  2.652424  90  0.2      4.38  -110.4
## 4 1998 0.5160826  2.244359  3.192511  3.480557 120  0.2      4.38  -110.4
## 5 1998 0.7561210  2.568411  3.552568  3.972636 150  0.2      4.38  -110.4
## 6 1998 0.9481517  3.984638  7.333173  9.841575 180  0.2      4.38  -110.4
##   freqs
## 1   591
## 2   350
## 3   221
## 4   290
## 5   331
## 6   820
```